# Trying to make button stay disabled when input not valid

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to make button stay disabled when input not valid...

I am using just simple Javascript validation. I can't make it work. Help please?

```
const hasInvalidInput = (inputList) => {
return inputList.some((inputElement) => {
    return !inputElement.validity.valid;
});
```

};

```
const toggleButtonState = (inputList, buttonElement, inactiveButtonClass) => {
if (hasInvalidInput(inputList)) {
    buttonElement.classList.add(inactiveButtonClass);
    buttonElement.setAttribute("disabled", "");
} else {
    buttonElement.classList.remove(inactiveButtonClass);
    buttonElement.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
}
```

};

```
const checkInputValidity = (formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass, errorClass) => {
if (!inputElement.validity.valid) {
    showInputError(formElement, inputElement, inputElement.validationMessage, inputErrorClass, errorClass);
} else {
    hideInputError(formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass, errorClass);
}
```

};

const showInputError = (formElement, inputElement, errorMessage) => {
const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`.${inputElement.id}-error`);
inputElement.classList.add("popup__error");
errorElement.textContent = errorMessage;
errorElement.classList.add("popup__error_visible");
};

```
const hideInputError = (formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass, errorClass) => {
const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`.${inputElement.id}-error`);
inputElement.classList.remove(inputErrorClass);
errorElement.classList.remove(errorClass);
errorElement.textContent = "";
```

};

```
const setEventListeners = (formElement, inputSelector, submitButtonSelector, inactiveButtonClass, inputErrorClass, errorClass) => {
const inputList = Array.from(formElement.querySelectorAll(inputSelector));
const buttonElement = formElement.querySelector(submitButtonSelector);

inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
    inputElement.addEventListener("input", () => {
        checkInputValidity(formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass, errorClass);
        toggleButtonState(inputList, buttonElement, inactiveButtonClass);
    });
});
```

};

```
const enableValidation = ({
formSelector,
inputSelector,
submitButtonSelector,
inactiveButtonClass,
inputErrorClass,
errorClass,
```

}) => {

```
const formList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(formSelector));
formList.forEach((formElement) => {
    formElement.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
    setEventListeners(
        formElement,
        inputSelector,
        submitButtonSelector,
        inactiveButtonClass,
        inputErrorClass,
        errorClass
    );
});
```

};

```
enableValidation({
formSelector: ".popup__form",
inputSelector: ".popup__input",
submitButtonSelector: ".popup__button",
inactiveButtonClass: "popup__button_disabled",
inputErrorClass: "popup__error",
errorClass: "popup__error_visible"
```

});

Comment: HTML5 has very good built-in functionality for handling form input (see attributes "pattern", "max/minLength" etc) Every piece of JavaScript and CSS that you develop is something you will need to test and support forever, and can create problems down the line when requirements change. Doing this in HTML is "safer" simply because there's less you can break in HTML

Comment: I was able to fix part of it. But now I have other issue about the other button. I don't think it can be done only through HTML but I am a beginner so, not so sure. I need to make the button disabled everytime is opened for the second time.